# The reading of 砂利

Tags: kanji, readings

砂利 I am fairly sure is normally read as じゃり but I saw that an alternate reading of ざり exists.

1. Is the ざり reading at all used in the modern language?
2. Why じゃ・ざ and not しゃ・さ?

Comment: I feel like there are other words that do this "inexplicably voicing the first mora" thing too (though I can't think of any examples off the top of my head), so maybe those could offer some insight into #2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The readings `サ・シャ` are from the Chinese morpheme `shā`.  Usually, when `砂` is read `サ` or `シャ`, it represents the Japanese version of this morpheme.

In this case, `砂` represents `ザ・ジャ`, which has a similar sound and meaning.  Since the reading isn't *quite* the same, it's a hint that it *might* not represent the same morpheme.  I decided to search for support for this idea by looking into the etymology of `じゃり`.  Although I don't have access to 日本国語大辞典 myself, I found a blogger who researched the subject and [posted](http://hyszem.exblog.jp/1942252/#1942252_1) about it:

> いずれにせよ、「砂利」は漢語ではなく、中世末期から近世初期のころに、和語の「ざり」を表す熟字として案出された〝漢語めかし〟の和製漢字表記ということになります。

This seemed to confirm the idea.  It appears that `じゃり` was originally of Japanese origin, and was spelled with the kanji `砂利` at a later date.  Presumably they were chosen because `砂` represented a similar meaning, while `砂` and `利` together represented a similar sound.  Because of this, the reading became an exception.

As for your other question, it appears that both `じゃり` and `ざり` used to be common, but `じゃり` is more common in modern Japanese.  Perhaps someone else will be able to be more specific on this point.

*(I'm a bit outside my comfort zone on this post, so if anyone has corrections or confirmation to give, I would be most grateful.)*

Comment: This answer needs revision--I appear to have mixed up my sources, and the link here doesn't seem to say what this answer suggests.  I read *somewhere* about a historical interplay between さ and しゃ, though.  I should come back to this answer and fix it after doing more research…